# android implement both touch listner and long click listner on textview at the same time

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I added both ontouchlistner and onlongclicklistner to a textview. But now everytime onlongclicklistner is invoking. Touch listner is not invoking. I want to invoke ontouchlistner on touch and longclick listner on longclick of about 70sec.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have more than one listener attached to a view that might respond to the same user input, you need to make sure you return true from your listener's event when you have handled the event and want to prevent further dispatching, and return false otherwise.

Comment: i had given that. But long click is invoking first. i want to invoke touch listner first. can we give priority to this events

Comment: if you remove the long click listener, do you get the touch events?  Sounds kinda fishy...onTouch should be firing first regardless.  If anything is getting short circuited it should be the long click listener

Comment: sorry. long click is not iinvoking.

Comment: You should update the question because the way it's currently phrased is misleading (sounds like onLongClick IS firing and onTouch is not).  return false from onTouch.  have you tried that?

Comment: So what should i do to invoke long click. Its invoking only after going to the touch

Comment: Well, that's how it works.  The user touches the screen for both of these events, so there's no simple way of knowing the difference in the onTouch ACTION_DOWN event if they're going to do long click or not.  What are you doing in onTouch?  Is it dragging, or can you replace onTouch with onClick?  I typically overlap onClick and onLongClick but I have never done onTouch with onLongClick, probably because of the problem you're facing now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4254/discussion-between-user760321-and-rich)